# How to install youtube-dl ubuntu 18.04

Tags: youtube-dl, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to install youtube-dl for my Ubuntu, I used apt, apt-get and even python pip, It installs successfully, but it doesn't work due to the version was the march version(something around 2018.03.xx), I tried to `sudo apt update` and reinstalled the pkg again but no difference(same version) and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

the march update is not the latest version, If we looked at debian site for the pkg:

[youtube-dl for debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/youtube-dl/download)

it has a new version(2018.09.10),
if you have the old version you should run:

```
sudo apt remove youtube-dl
sudo apt autoremove
```

that should remove the old version, now download the pkg from the link and go to terminal type:

```
sudo dpkg --install /path/youtube-dl-pkg-name.deb
```

type your password and done!
to see the version type on terminal:

```
youtube-dl --version
```